# Error Connection Remote Queue Manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to a remote queue manager via host address, but when I try to configure the connection using MQ Explorer, it comes back an error message

Reason 2009 (AMQ4059)

Anyone can help me to understand why MQ Explorer gives me this error?

Comment: You would need to have the MQ admin look at the queue manager logs to tell you the reason for the connection broken error.

Comment: Generally speaking, RC of 2009 means that the channel name is incorrect. Verify that you have inputted the correct server connection channel name. Also, channel names are case sensitive (e.g. JAVA.CHL is not the same as java.chl).

Comment: Did you find a resolution to your issue?